# SQL Distinct on everycolumn but one (id)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to do such operation? I have table with structure of:

```
id(unique, serial), parameter(text), description(text), severity(text), topic_id(int, foreign key)
```

Which allow users to add identical rows (having the same `parameter`, `description`, `topic_id` and `severity` but with different `id`

when I execute query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PARAMETER,
                description,
                severity
FROM task
WHERE topic_id=851;
```

which results in

```
  parameter     | description     | severity | 
----------------+-----------------+----------+
do when possible| ask bob         | 0        |      
      time diff | check time serv | 2        |      
         urgent | fix it asap     | 3        |      
         test   | no details aval | 3        |      
         test2  | no details aval | 2        |      
         test3  | no details aval | 2        |
```

I get the result of `6 rows` containg information I want. However I need this query to return `id` for each row (so I can process it properly server side)

When I change query to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,
                PARAMETER,
                description,
                severity
FROM task
WHERE topic_id=851;

 id   |  parameter      | description     | severity | 
------+-----------------+-----------------+----------+
 30045| do when possible| ask bob         | 0        |      
 30046| time diff       | check time serv | 2        |  
 30044| urgent          | fix it asap     | 3        |      
 27188| urgent          | fix it asap     | 3        |      
 24323| urgent          | fix it asap     | 3        |      
 30047| test            | no details aval | 3        |
 30048| test2           | no details aval | 2        |      
 30049| test3           | no details aval | 2        |
```

Result set contains `id` field however it contains `8 rows`.

Is it possible to set `distinct` on every column but `id`?

Comment: You want 8 ids but 6 rows of data ?? I didn't get your question...

Comment: I want 6 unique rows like in 1st querry but with id

Comment: How is possible you obtain repeated ids? Can you post your rows info?

Comment: there is no repeated ids ;) for example rows with id (30044, 27188 and 24323) are the same

Comment: Can you show how the expected result set (6 rows), Id column data should looks like?

Comment: As @angel_navarro has pointed out, your language is imprecise. If you want the `id` for each row, and `id` is unique, then there are no repeated rows. If "repeated" means "columns other than id have the same values" then that is different - but if two `id`s can have the same other values, which of the `id`s would you keep? You can't just arbitrarily throw one away. I see this often with `DISTINCT`, where beginners find a query returns multiple rows, so they just use `DISTINCT` to make all the rows in the result set unique - but the core problem is that they don't really understand their data.

Comment: To ask a different way; If row 30044, 27188 and 24323 are the same - how is the logic to decide which of the 3 id's you want out in your "distinct" list?

Comment: I'm sorry for misleading. I have edited question.

Comment: Then just do a distinct on your select list, but don't select the id

Comment: I need this id to be returned in order to process it properly in my php script..

Comment: Then I'll ask again - how do you know which id is going to be returned when there are 3 different id's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is something not intuitive in your data, so it's probable you can improve your data model.

Then, with the information you have, maybe you can use something like this:

```
select distinct t1.id,
                t1.PARAMETER,
                t1.description,
                t1.severity
from task t1
where t1.topic_id=851
  and t1.id = (
               select max(t2.id) 
               from task t2 
               where t1.parameter = t2.parameter 
                 and t1.description = t2.description 
                 and t1.severity = t2.severity)
;
```

Another way:

```
select distinct parameter, description, severity, max(id)
from task
where topic_id=851
group by parameter, description, severity
;
```

Comment: Fantastic!! Kind regards

Comment: Btw, you don't need DISTINCT in both queries anymore :-)

Comment: Oh, you're right! I forgot it. Thanks for your aclaration ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is what `DISTINCT ON` does exactly:

> SELECT DISTINCT eliminates duplicate rows from the result. **SELECT DISTINCT ON eliminates rows that match on all the specified expressions.**
>
> http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-select.html

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (parameter, description, severity)
       id, parameter, description, severity
FROM task
WHERE ...
```